# Import my python module to rstudio

Tags: python, rstudio, r-markdown, python-import

I have developed few modules in python and I want to import them to rstudio RMarkdown file. However, I am not sure how I can do it.

For example, I can't do `from code.extract_feat.cluster_blast import fill_df_by_blast as fill_df` as I am used to do it in pycharm.

Any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use [`reticulate` knitr engine](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/eng_python.html)?

Comment: no I am not using it, I am not sure if that will help because all what I want to do is to import some modules in python files that I have implemented (without using the rstudi IDE. Any hint?

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve your goal with `reticulate` package: read [this post](https://longhowlam.wordpress.com/2017/04/10/test-driving-python-integration-in-r-using-the-reticulate-package/)

Answer (score 0):

First I had to make a setup.py file for my project.
activate the virtual environment corresponding to my project `source activate`, then run `python setup.py develop`

Now, I can import my own python library from R as I installed it in my environment.